# How to check if Range.Interior.ColorIndex=xlNone in a simple way?

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried several ways to check whether any cell within a range is colored and wonder if there is a simpler way to do the same thing.

My 1st try:

```
If Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then MsgBox ("Nothing is colored") Else MsgBox ("Sth is colored")
```

It worked well, though what I really want is to trigger sth when any cell within a range is colored.

---

2nd try:

```
If Not Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then MsgBox ("Sth is colored") Else MsgBox ("Nothing is colored")
```

It didn't work. Seems that VBA don't understand the negation of "Range.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone".

I know I can do it this way:

```
If Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then Else MsgBox ("Sth is colored")
```

However it's not that intuitive and not easy to use when there are many conditions.

---

3rd try:

```
If CBool(Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone) = False Then MsgBox ("Sth is colored")
```

This time I tried to convert the ...ColorIndex=xlNone thing to a boolean value, but it returned a "invalid use of null" when any cell was actually colored.

---

4th try:

```
Dim b As Boolean
If Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then b = True Else b = False
If b = False Then MsgBox ("Sth is colored")
```

It worked fine, but it's not simple enough for me. I want to do this in 1-2 lines and no use of variable if possible.

Is there any simpler way to do the same task? Any inspiration is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your 2nd try you are negating `Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex` and comparing it to `xlNone` instead of negating the comparison

Comment: @Nacorid Thx for reply. However `Not (Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone)` and `Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone` didn't work as well.

Comment: Ah, yes, `ColorIndex` on a `Range` with different colored cells will return `Null`. You should loop over your cells to check. Or infer from `Null` that at least one cell is colored differently from the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nacorid @EvR

Thank you for your suggestions! I've eventually figured out the answer I want.

```
If Not Range("A1:B1").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Or IsNull(Range("A1:B1").Interior.ColorIndex) Then MsgBox ("colored")
```

Now I can do the Interior.ColorIndex check in one line, plus I can add all others conditions in this one single line. Thanks for your tips again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a select Case statement; The result of Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex could be xlNone, Null or a Long but Null can't be catched by the Select Statement(so the Else Clause) 
and no need for variables plus it's easy to expand with more conditions.

```
    Select Case Range("A1:O50").Interior.ColorIndex
        Case xlNone: MsgBox "Nothing is colored"
        Case Else: MsgBox "Sth is colored"
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim n As Long
n = 0
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = sht.Range("A1:O20")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next cell
Debug.Print n & " colored cells found"
End Sub
```